# Only visible spaces seen?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gdm, ubuntu-gnome

I recently converted Ubuntu to Ubuntu GNOME by removing Unity and installing GNOME from the repositories and removed LightDM too. My account was working, but the rest of the family user accounts are having a problem. Instead of letters, vertical rectangles are seen, like this.

[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]

GDM and my GNOME is working, but others are having problems. The boxes are appearing only in all apps like terminal and Firefox, chrome and others, but the GNOME interface and notifications is okay. I run Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.

Update:- Switched from GDM to LightDM, and now LightDM notifications also has boxes! Please help!

Update 2:- Now they are not logging in after update to GNOME 3.12.2! They can only be logged in by a virtual console and my entire family doesn't know how to use the command line!

Update 3:- Here is the output of `ls /var/log/apt/history.*` as asked by Volker Siegel

```
/var/log/apt/history.log
```

Update 4:- I just do not care anymore about this. I am having idiotic problems and am reinstalling Ubuntu. These problems never happened with my previous install of 14.04.

Comment: are the other accounts using different language (other than english)?

Comment: Where are the rectangles shown,, exactly? And where not?

Comment: The entire system is using the same language and locale, that is confirmed. Volker Siegel, I have updated my question.

Comment: Ok, open `/var/log/apt/history.log` in an editor and search for Remove and font, to check for things looking like a font was removed. But I start to think it's something different.

Comment: @Volker Siegel There is no removal of any font.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something like that myself during an update. I think an important font is missing, maybe accidently uninstalled by a (bad) dependeency.

So take a look at the **installed packages**, if there are main **font packages missing**.

You can use the **history log** of the package installer in `/var/log/apt/`.

To list removals which removed a package matching `*font*`:

`zgrep 'Remove: .*font' /var/log/apt/history.*`

This lists very long lines, so let's see the first part of lines:
`zgrep 'Remove: .*font' /var/log/apt/history.* | cut -c 1-120`

Or take a look at the full lines, but highlight the word "font" to find them:
`zgrep 'Remove: .*font' /var/log/apt/history.* | grep --color=always font`

(To make sure, did you restart the computer? Normally restarting the DM would do, but as you changed that, better reboot)

Comment: I did not get any output.

Comment: @IAnsari Hmm... how many files are listed with `ls /var/log/apt/history.*`? What exactly did you run (cut and paste)

Comment: I updated my question. Please check Update 2 and 3. if you have a solution for 2, then please mention it too. If you don't have one, then put that aside for others. I have listed the output of your command in update 2.